# @PostMapping not working. HTTP 415 Unsupported MediaType Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created a @RestController and mapped a @PostMapping request.

I am passing Content Type as "application/json" to the controller where I am reading the JSON with @RequestBody annotation mapping it to my Model class object.

> @RestController:

```
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public UserDetails save(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
    System.out.println("from json input : "+user.idVal+" : "+user.getName());
    service.save(user);
    JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
    jsn.put("Result", user.getName());
    return user;
}
```

> HTTP Request

```
{
"idVal":"asdadasd",
"name":"TestUser"
}
```

> Model Class

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    public String idVal;
    public String name;

    public String getId() {
        return idVal;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.idVal = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I am using Postman as the REST Client.

Following is the error I am getting:

```
HTTP Status 415 â€“ Unsupported Media Type
Type Status Report

Description The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
```

I have tried as following:

```
@PostMapping(value="/saveUser", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public UserDetails save(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
    System.out.println("from json input : "+user.idVal+" : "+user.getName());
    service.save(user);
    JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
    jsn.put("Result", user.getName());
    return user;
}
```

> Edit:

Below is the complete Postman Request:

```
 POST /Zcrud/saveUser HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fa4cfc76-d60c-f8dd-53b9-fd8b0b27ef7d

{
    "idVal":"asdadasd",
    "name":"TestUser"
}
```

Response:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.31</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Do you have this dependency defined in your pom 
`<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>`  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703540/spring-mvc-requestbody-receive-an-object-wrapper-with-non-primitive-attributes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: 1) Why are you creating that useless `JSONObject` in your controller? 2) Please post the full HTTP request log.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `application/json` in your request from **Postman** to **Your Application**. But your server doesn't understand what `application/json` is.

So, you have to define in your server too, what type of request is is gonna handle, and what type of response it is gonna produce.

to do so, change your `@RestController`'s `@PostMapping` like below

```
@PostMapping(value ="/saveUser", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public UserDetails save(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
   System.out.println("from json input : "+user.idVal+" : "+user.getName());
   service.save(user);
   JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
   jsn.put("Result", user.getName());
   return user;
}
```

Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: Which jar being used for "MediaType" ?

Comment: `MediaType` comes from this `org.springframework.http` package, full path for className is `org.springframework.http.MediaType;` So it comes with `springframework`.

Comment: Also, for your interest, the `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` is nothing but a final static string whose value is `"application/json"` So you can hard code it in your `consumes` and `produces` param. Anyways, was that solution helpful??

Comment: Thnx but it still did not work! I hv updated the Post

Comment: In that case, I would request you to provide the exact request made by postman !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172679/discussion-between-mad-man-and-harshvardhan-solanki).

Answer (score 1):

Add Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose to your @PostMapping annotation

Comment: what does "odata=verbose" do?